# $\mathbb{Z}/n$ is not isomorphic to a semidirect product of $\mathbb{Z}/k$ and $\mathbb{Z}/q$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $n = kq$ for some integers $k,q>1$. Consider the quotient map
        $\pi: \mathbb{Z}/n \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/q$ obtained by modding
        out by the normal subgroup generated by $k \in \mathbb{Z}/n$. Show
        that there is a map of sets $\sigma: \mathbb{Z}/q \rightarrow
  \mathbb{Z}/n$ so that $\pi \circ \sigma = \text{id}$. Show that 
        $\sigma$ cannot be chosen to be a homomorphism. Deduce that
        $\mathbb{Z}/n$ is not isomorphic to a semidirect product of
        $\mathbb{Z}/k$ and $\mathbb{Z}/q$.

The progress I made so far is :

$ker(\pi)= \langle k \rangle$. Take $q' \in \mathbb{Z}/q$. Then, there exists
        the preimage of $q'$, $n'+ker(\pi)=n'+ \langle k \rangle$ where $n' \in \mathbb{Z}/n$.
        For each $q' \in \mathbb{Z}/q$, there exists in the coset $n'+\langle k \rangle$,
        such that $\pi(n')=q$. Hence, there exists $\sigma$ such that $\pi \circ \sigma=id$.

But, I still cannot see why $\sigma$ cannot be a homomorphism.
How should I approach?
Any hint?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't understand this. For $n=6=2\cdot 3$ we have even a direct product $\mathbb{Z}/6\simeq \mathbb{Z}/2\times \mathbb{Z}/3$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes... That's very strange. I just assumed that the question was truthful.

Comment: Well I wouldn't call it a *proper* semidirect product (a direct product is a "trivial" semidirect product), since proper semidirect products are nonabelian. *Maybe* that's what the professor meant?

Comment: @oxeimon that is an unlikely interpretation. If it were what is meant, the proof would be: $\mathbb{Z}/n$ is abelian.

Comment: @DavidHill I agree, hence the *emphasized* "*Maybe*"